# How to define custom themes in vue.js using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the colours of a Vue template (uses vuetify) that I am using but after pouring over the docs for a day I am not sure what else I can try.

My main file:

```
//src/main.ts

import '@babel/polyfill';
// Import Component hooks before component definitions
import './component-hooks';
import Vue from 'vue';
import './plugins/vuetify';
import './plugins/vee-validate';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from '@/store';
import './registerServiceWorker';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

the vuetify plugin file:

```
//src/plugins/vuetify.ts

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
      themes: {
          light: {
            primary: '#17242d', 
          },
          dark: {
            primary: '#17242d',
        },
      },
    },
});
```

I tried many variations of defining different themes in the vuetify.ts file but nothing changes the colours in of any component that references (for example) "primary".

Other people seemed to have success with my approach: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuetify-how-to-add-a-custom-color-theme-after-create-the-project/40241/2

Am I missing something? Where should I look next?

EDIT 1: Removed reference to vuetify.min.css in main.ts. Now I can see my selected colour for a few ms before it switches back to default after server restart.

EDIT 2: Using the web inspector I could figure out that the primary colour is appended with !important (which as far as I understood means that this definition supersedes all others). How would I fid where that definition is?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing Vuetify from `node_modules` within your `main.ts` you should rather import the file from your plugins folder.

So in your `main.ts` instead of

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
```

try this

```
import './src/plugins/vuetify.ts';
```

Comment: I implemented your changes. Now I can see my desired color for a few ms but then it switches back to the primary

Comment: Initially my answer was a bit wrong. You should - in any case - avoid importing minified vuetify css. Vuetify css (bundled) sets the primary color with !important option. However, in dev mode and therefore in a non bundled version, it's always set to default so you can verride it. That said - Don't import the css file individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
//src/plugins/vuetify.ts
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#17242d",
      },
      dark: {
        primary: "#17242d",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
//src/main.ts
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

[Repo](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/vuetify-app) with [demo](https://chriswong979.github.io/vuetify-app/)